# Select points from Buffers in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, buffer

I have a buffers and I want to select all points within each of the buffer and output it as a table. That means one buffer may have 0 to about 10 points in it.
I have tried spatial Join and intersect in ArcMap 10.1. Its returning where there is zero points correctly. In instances with more than one, it lists only one randomly instead of all of them
What other tool can I use?

Comment: I have found a way out. There is a checkbox that needed me to tick ONE TO MANY relationships under the spatial join

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tool "Select Layer By Location":

ArcToolBox--> Data Management Tools--> Layer and table views--> Select Layer By Location.

Keep the point layer from which you want selection as "Input Feature Layer" and buffered layer as selecting features. Apply 'intersection'.

After selection, u can export it.

Comment: This still gives results  as above.